# Error in this mysql query

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT t2.workingstatus 
FROM SKILL_SET t1, Employee_Status t2 
  ON t1.USER_ID = t2.USER_ID 
WHERE t1.TRAININGS_ATTENDED='java'
```

what is the error in this query

Comment: You are trying to mix two different join syntaxes. So, skip the ',' and use `INNER JOIN` instead.

Comment: SELECT t2.workingstatus 
FROM SKILL_SET t1 join Employee_Status t2 
  ON t1.USER_ID = t2.USER_ID 
WHERE t1.TRAININGS_ATTENDED='java'

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: ya actually i am trying from the hibernate hql but join is not working properly

Comment: Pedant alert: "training" not "trainings" is grammatically correct for your field name. I seem to see this horror everywhere these days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should post your error messages as well .

try as below :

```
SELECT t2.workingstatus 
FROM SKILL_SET t1 JOIN Employee_Status t2 -- (can be LEFT JOIN)
  ON t1.USER_ID = t2.USER_ID 
WHERE t1.TRAININGS_ATTENDED='java';
```

JOIN needed to be specified .

Answer (score 0):

Use ON keyword with join query

```
SELECT t2.workingstatus 
FROM SKILL_SET t1 INNER JOIN Employee_Status t2 
  ON t1.USER_ID = t2.USER_ID 
WHERE t1.TRAININGS_ATTENDED='java'
```